MAUI Project from .NET 7 to .NET 8 with Xcode 16 and macOS Updates
I'm facing serious issues after updating my hybrid .NET MAUI project from .NET 7 to .NET 8. This project was started in 2021, and everything worked well under .NET 7. Recently, I updated the following:
.NET: Upgraded from .NET 7 to .NET 8.
macOS: Upgraded to the latest macOS version.
Xcode: Updated to Xcode 16.
Visual Studio: Now using Visual Studio 17.11.5, which is supposed to support Xcode 16.
Project Structure:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor"> for the MAUI app.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor"> for the Shared Library.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly"> for the WASM app 

Issue:
I’m getting the following error for my iOS builds (in both Debug and Release modes):
MessagingRemoteException: An error occurred on client 
Build1808303 while executing a reply for topic 
xvs/build/18.0.8303/execute- 
task/{AppName}/78f1110002fWriteAppManifest
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: 
path2

This error points to the Xamarin.Shared.targets file at line 643.
Steps Taken:
Verified that the Info.plist file exists and is not empty.
Cleaned and rebuilt the solution.
Enabled detailed build logs, but the error persists.
Tried switching from Release to Debug mode, but the issue remains.
I’m unable to run the iOS Simulator or debug the app when pairing with my MacBook Air.
Checked project configurations for both Android and iOS, and they seem consistent.
I’m stuck and can't get past this error, making it impossible to debug or publish to TestFlight. Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated!

Please try to clean the bin/obj folders and delete the XMA cache folder, then try again. Please follow the steps on document Clearing the Broker, IDB, Build, and Designer Agents on the Mac.
